# Pytest: run test one by one

Tags: python, pytest

I've multiple test functions created in a file. Example:

```
def testA():
   change_user_permission_to_allow()
   assert action == success
   change_user_permission_to_deny()

def testB():
   assert action == fail

## Multiple other tests...
```

By default, user are denied for action. When I run `testB` individually, it passes. When I run the test file as a whole.

> pytest testfile.py

The `testB` fails. When I debug the user permission is allowed. Seems like `testA` is making issue in `testB`. Is there a way to tell pytest to run test one after another?

Comment: This is a typical symptom of an incomplete cleanup. Unit tests should undo everything they changed at the end.

Comment: @KlausD. That is done at the end of `TestA` as you can see. I'm unsure whats causing the incomplete cleanup

Comment: I only see that you seem to run a function that **seems** to do the opposite of the function before. Without showing the actual content of this function it is hard say what was not cleaned up.

Comment: _Seems like testA is making issue in testB_ is a symptom of an incomplete cleanup. Fix `testA` so it resets user permissions correctly. If you need help with that, please provide a [mcve]. The current answer will make your test suite more fragile instead of fixing things on the long run.

Answer (score 2):

- you can read the [pytest-ordering: run your tests in order](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#pytest-ordering-run-your-tests-in-order)
- With pytest-ordering, you can change the default ordering as follows:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.order2
def test_foo():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.order1
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

```
$ py.test test_foo.py -vv
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- env/bin/python
plugins: ordering
collected 2 items

test_foo.py:7: test_bar PASSED
test_foo.py:3: test_foo PASSED

=========================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this also

```
  --sw, --stepwise      exit on test failure and continue from last failing
                        test next time
  --sw-skip, --stepwise-skip
                        ignore the first failing test but stop on the next
                        failing test.
                        implicitly enables --stepwise.
```